# How to plot line s=(cost,sint,0) while 0<=t<=pi

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, matlab-figure

I want to plot in matlab line  s=(cost,sint,0) while 0<=t<=pi

```
t=0:.001:pi;
x=cos(t);
y=sin(t);
z=sin(t).*0;
mesh(x,y,z)
```

I get an error that z must be a matrix? how can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`plot3`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html), not [`mesh`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html). The function [`mesh`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html) is used for plotting surfaces in 3D. For plotting lines in 3D you need [`plot3`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html):

```
t=0:.001:pi;
x=cos(t);
y=sin(t);
z=sin(t).*0;
plot3(x,y,z)
```

Note that `z` can be defined more simply as `z=zeros(size(t))`:

```
t=0:.001:pi;
x=cos(t);
y=sin(t);
z=zeros(size(t));
plot3(x,y,z)
```

Also, since `z` is zero in your case, you could use [`plot`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) for drawing the line in 2D, and then use [`view`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html) for changing to the standard 3D view:

```
t=0:.001:pi;
x=cos(t);
y=sin(t);
plot(x,y)
view(3)
```

Comment: Damn! I wasted time getting the link :(

Comment: Hahaha. I've upvoted your answer for being more to the point. You could have answered first and then added the link

Answer (score 2):

Use [`plot3(x, y, z)`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html).‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏